# Angular js reload

Tags: angularjs, json, laravel, laravel-5

Pessoa, notei que sempre que dou reload na pagina, enquanto pagina está sendo carregada, ela mostra todas as chaves {{}} dos scopos do meu projeto, é normal ? a pagina que contém os scopos vindo de um get json é em php....

Comment: Coloque o código na sua pergunta!

Answer (score 1):

É 'normal' acontecer isso, pois o angular só processa a view depois que o DOM está completamente carregado. Enquanto isso não acontece, os {{ }} são apenas caracteres normais.

Existe uma diretiva do angular para prevenir isso, a `ngCloak`, que simplesmente ajuda a esconder todo o conteúdo até que o angular processe o DOM.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Basta colocar essa diretiva em um elemento pai da página (é importante que seja junto ou abaixo do elemento que contiver a diretiva ng-app), e após finalizar a carga, o angular remove sozinho as referências a ele, fazendo com que tudo apareça normalmente.

Por fim, pra funcionar corretamente, no seu CSS principal, você precisa adicionar o seguinte código:

```css
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Espero ter ajudado! Abs!